# Decoding broken frame or the frame whose reference frames are broken in H.264

Tags: video-streaming, decode, h.264, mpeg

While I designing the video streaming system, I have some questions related to the decoding. I need to know whether the decoder of h.264 could decode the broken (which means that some data is missed) I frame.

Assume that, While I send the media data to the client, some media packets of I frame are dropped. Then, can the client (or the decoder) decodes the broken I frame?

In addition, with the broken I frame, can the decoder decodes the P-frame which refers to the broken I frame? (Say, the P frame is not broken).

I guess that the decoder definitely produces the error. However, even with the error, can I see the decoded picture partially?

Thanks